# ceil() function behavior in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select, aggregate

While using the ceil() in postgresql, I found some strange behavior of it, Please see SQL :

```
Select  
     *,
     ceil( (550*0.5)/100 ),
     ceil( (58*5)/100 ),
FROM
   XYZ
```

If I focus on the output of ceil functions it is strange :

- ceil( (550*0.5)/100 ) Returning 3 ( Which converts 2.75 to 3 )
- ceil((58*5)/100 ) Returning 2 ( Which converts 2.9 to 2 )

Why 2nd statement returning 2 if it is closed to the greater integer 3 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Description**
>   The PostgreSQL ceil function returns the smallest integer value that is **greater than or equal** to a number.

And according [Postgres Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-math.html):

> Except where noted, any given form of a function returns the same data type as its argument.

As you can see it works properly, in fact, if you use integers the returned value is one integer `(58 * 5) / 100)` returns 2 but if you forces it to decimal `(58.0 * 5.0) / 100.0` then it returns 2.9.

> ```
> select 
>      (550 * 0.5) / 100 as C1,
>      ceil((550 * 0.5) / 100) as CEIL_C1,
>      (58 * 5) / 100 as C2,
>      ceil((58 * 5) / 100) as CEIL_C2,
>      (58.0 * 5.0) / 100.0 as C3,
>      ceil((58.0 * 5.0) / 100.0) as CEIL_C3
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
>                 c1 | ceil_c1 | c2 | ceil_c2 |                 c3 | ceil_c3
> -----------------: | ------: | -: | :------ | -----------------: | ------:
> 2.7500000000000000 |       3 |  2 | 2       | 2.9000000000000000 |       3
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b32f684fcb37e1e92f22a74ec302c59e)*

Comment: Yes thats what I found and its correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

> integer division truncates the result

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html)